# Is there an app to keep screen on when another (video surveillance) app is running?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, video, screensaver

I'm using this mobile video surveillance app on my iPad, called [Exacq Mobile 3](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exacq-mobile-3/id416566873?mt=8) to monitor cameras in our store when I'm in the backroom.

It works for what I need it, except that there's one seemingly trivial issue -- this app doesn't disable battery saving mode of the iPad when it's in the camera display mode:

[image]

and lets it turn off the screen if I don't touch it for a few minutes. **And that is very frustrating!**

I have to remember to *touch the screen* once in awhile to make it stay up. And if I can't do it at the moment (if I'm busy holding something) the iPad screen goes black, and then this app becomes very *janky* when I turn the iPad back on. (So to fix it I have to force-quit the app and restart it.)

All this takes about 30 seconds to do. Not much. But it becomes very annoying when you have to repeat it 20 times!

I tried contacting the company (about couple years ago) about fixing this and got nowhere. Awful customer service!

So being a Mac user, I know that there's a macOS app called Caffeine that you can click on the menu bar and it will keep screen on indefinitely. Is there a similar app for an iPad?

PS. I tried disabling the feature that turns the screen off in the iOS settings, but unfortunately it also messes me up when I'm using this iPad for something else that doesn't need keeping the screen on. For instance, if I'm browsing the web and then lay it down and then come back to it a few hours later, the battery on the iPad will be completely dead.

*Again sounds like a trivial issue but the obtuse developer of the app can't seem to fix it...*

Comment: It’s a simple fix for the developer but your only option is to have the auto lock never